# Use Google places API to search my own places instead of places provide from google

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to develop an application of geolocation restaurant , so on the map, I will have to search for restaurants, display them on a listView , just like what Google API places do. But I just want to see the data coming from my database not one that comes from google.

Is it possible to that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should fetch those POIs position/location from your own server, get all geolocation and put their marker on you Map. If you want to get address from your POI, you can then decode it using Geocoder